# Percentage histogram with facet_grid: x variable is a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet-grid

I want to split a percentage histogram (that integrates to 100%) into two facets using `facet_grid`. However, when splitting to facets, each facet by itself doesn't integrate to 100%. This kind of question [has been resolved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691727/6105259) in the past, but I cannot translate that solution to my current situation where x is a factor, and thus a histogram using `stat(density)` doesn't work.

### My Data

Dataframe with two columns. `equipment` denotes whether a household has enough equipment for homeschooling, and `children_n` denotes number of children.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- 
structure(list(equipment = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), children_n = c(4, 
4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 9, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
3, 3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 
1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 8, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 
3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 
3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
8, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 6, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 9, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 1, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
8, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 
1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 
2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -1059L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


df

## # A tibble: 1,059 x 2
##    equipment children_n
##        <dbl>      <dbl>
##  1         1          4
##  2         0          4
##  3         1          2
##  4         1          2
##  5         0          2
##  6         1          1
##  7         1          1
##  8         1          3
##  9         1          2
## 10         1          3
## # ... with 1,049 more rows
```

In cases where number of children is above 6, I want to collapse those cases to one category of "6+".

```r
df %<>%
  mutate_at(vars(children_n), as.character) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(children_n), recode, "9" = "6_plus", "8" = "6_plus", "7" = "6_plus", "6" = "6_plus") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(children_n), fct_relevel, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6_plus")

glimpse(df)

## Rows: 1,059
## Columns: 2
## $ equipment  <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...
## $ children_n <fct> 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 6_plus, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6_plus, 1, 2, 1, 2,...
```

Now I want to plot the proportion of number of children in two separate panels: one panel for families who have enough equipment, and another panel for families who don't have enough equipment:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = children_n, y = equipment)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat = "count" , fill = "darkblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(((..count..)/sum(..count..)), accuracy = 1),
                y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)) ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5, color = "darkblue") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~ equipment, labeller = as_labeller(c("1" = "have enough equipment", 
                                                   "0" = "don't have enough equipment")))
```

#### This gives two panels that *DON'T* integrate to 100% independently:

[image: two_panels_dont_integrate]

### Trying to solve the problem

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691727/6105259) that describes the same intention and problem. The chosen solution suggests defining the `geom_histogram` as density so it integrates to 100%. But this won't work in my case because `stat(density)` asks that the x variable will be continuous, unlike my case where x is a factor.

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = children_n, y = equipment)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density) * 6), binwidth = 6, fill = "darkblue") +
  facet_grid(~ equipment, labeller = as_labeller(c("1" = "have enough equipment", 
                                                   "0" = "don't have enough equipment")))
```

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is
> discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

Other approaches suggest using `..PANEL..` while others are strongly against it.
How can I get the two facets to show percents that independently integrate to 100%, in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Map the facetting variable on the `group` aes
2. Use e.g. `tapply` to get the total number per group or facet

BTW: I have put the code for the normalization inside a helper function to reduce the code duplication and readability

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df %<>%
  mutate_at(vars(children_n), as.character) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(children_n), recode, "9" = "6_plus", "8" = "6_plus", "7" = "6_plus", "6" = "6_plus") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(children_n), fct_relevel, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6_plus")

help <- function(count, group) {
  count / tapply(count, group, sum)[group]
}

df %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = children_n, y = equipment, group = equipment)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = help(..count.., ..group..)), stat = "count" , fill = "darkblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(help(..count.., ..group..), accuracy = 1),
                y = help(..count.., ..group..) ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5, color = "darkblue") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~ equipment, labeller = as_labeller(c("1" = "have enough equipment", 
                                                   "0" = "don't have enough equipment")))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad
```

[image]