# Assign custom colors to each plot of facet_wrap histograms in R - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I want to use facet_wrap in R to split my plots based on a certain column. Here is a working example I reproduced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690318/percentage-histogram-with-facet-wrap):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(age = runif(500, min = 10, max = 100), 
group = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 100))

#Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(age)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)), binwidth = 5) +
facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 3)
```

This produces plots, all in grey color (shown below). However, I want each plot be in a specific color. That is, they have the following color in order c("green","orange","blue","black", "red"). All bars in plot (a) be green, all in (b) be orange, and so on. These colors match my other plots and preserve consistency.
How can I achieve this task?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just add `fill=group` to your `aes()` call and `use a scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: Thanks. But I need exactly specific color to be assigned to each plot. Not random!

Comment: Fixed.  Reread your question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(age)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..), fill=group), binwidth = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green","orange","blue","black", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks. Just added `set.seed(1)` to my code, so that you can reproduce same plots as mine to inhibit confusion :)