# How to plot faceted histogram with percents using fill group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to plot a percentage histogram with facets and a group fill variable.
Similar things were discussed here, but without the fill variable.
[Percentage histogram with facet_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690318/percentage-histogram-with-facet-wrap)

The original solution with density produces, unfortunately, strange results.
In the following code: First geom_hist line produces incorrect group R line. The second geom_hist produces normal counts. How to print correct facet-wise percentages ?

```
values <- sample(c(4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512),1000,replace=TRUE)
groups <- sample(c("A","B","C","D"),1000,replace=TRUE)
daf <- data.frame(group=groups,value=values)
daf$state <- "S"
daf$state[daf$group == "A" & daf$value > 16] <- "R"
daf$state[daf$group == "B" & daf$value > 64] <- "R"
daf$state[daf$group == "C" & daf$value > 32] <- "R"
daf$state[daf$group == "D" & daf$value > 256] <- "R"

p <- ggplot(daf, aes(x=value,fill=state)) +
 geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)*0.5),binwidth=0.5) +
  # geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(count)),binwidth=0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "log2-trans",trans="log2",labels = scales::math_format(2^.x, format = log2),breaks = c(0.015625,0.03125,0.0625,0.125,0.25,0.5,0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Count")+
  facet_wrap(~ group,nrow=5,ncol=3,scales = "free")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mapping `state` on `fill` the densities are computed per facet *and* category of `state`. Instead, if you want the densities to be computed over all bins out both states you could set the `fill` color using `after_stat` in `geom_histogram` or as a second option compute the "density" or the percentages manually based on the counts:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

ggplot(daf, aes(x = value, fill = state)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(
      ave(count, PANEL, FUN = \(x) x / sum(x))
    )),
    binwidth = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "log2-trans", trans = "log2",
    labels = scales::math_format(2^.x, format = log2),
    breaks = c(
      0.015625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25,
      0.5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Count") +
  facet_wrap(~group, nrow = 5, ncol = 3, scales = "free") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea! The grouping is more complex, each facet has different criteria for R and S. The line ifelse(x > 256 ) is not appropriate, or only for one case. This is however not shown in the minimal example.

Comment: I adapted the example, to show that each groups has a different threshold.

Comment: Hi Peter, thx for updating. See my edit on how we could account for more complex rules.

Comment: Nice solution but in my real data I have dozens of rules. Therefore I need a way to use the group variable without access to PANEL.

Comment: Okay, I see. See my edit for a different approach.

Comment: What a crazy solution with ave :). The proportions of the last panel are not correct anymore. If you compare to geom_hist(y=..count..)

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Of course do we have to compute only per PANEL without taking the `group`ing into account. And in this case we don't need to multiply by .5. Already wondered ... (:

Comment: This works, but after all I it seems that barplots might be also appropriate here because most values are discrete. I am working on this